# Why my Codeigniter unable to connect multiple database?

Tags: codeigniter

I am junior of codeigniter, what I want to do is connect multiple database to retrieve the database data, but it is not working for me, keep return me 404 error page

here is my code

**config/database.php**

```
$active_group = 'qm';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['qm']['hostname'] = '192.168.0.128';
$db['qm']['username'] = 'callcenter';
$db['qm']['password'] = 'ca11c3nt3r';
$db['qm']['database'] = 'qm';
$db['qm']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['qm']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['qm']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['qm']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['qm']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['qm']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['qm']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['qm']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['qm']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['qm']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['qm']['stricton'] = FALSE;

/* call contact detail table */
$active_group = "reportcallcenter";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['reportcallcenter']['hostname'] = '192.168.0.128';
$db['reportcallcenter']['username'] = 'callcenter';
$db['reportcallcenter']['password'] = 'ca11c3nt3r';
$db['reportcallcenter']['database'] = 'reportcallcenter';
$db['reportcallcenter']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['reportcallcenter']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['reportcallcenter']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['reportcallcenter']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['reportcallcenter']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['reportcallcenter']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['reportcallcenter']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['reportcallcenter']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['reportcallcenter']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['reportcallcenter']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['reportcallcenter']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Qm extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->permission->is_logged_in();
        //load model
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('callcontactsdetails_model');
        $this->load->database('qm', TRUE);
        $this->load->database('reportcallcenter', TRUE);
    }

    function qm_form()
    {
        $data = array();
        $data['page'] = 'qm_form';
        if($query = $this->callcontactsdetails_model->get_all())
        {
            $data['recordings_record'] = $query;
        }
        $data['main'] = 'qm/qm_form';
        $data['js_function'] = array('qm');
        $this->load->view('template/template',$data);
    }
}//end of class
?>
```

**Model (I using My_model)**

```
<?php
class Callcontactsdetails_model extends MY_Model {
    protected $_table = 'callcontactsdetails';
    protected $primary_key = 'id';
}
?>
```

**My Screen Return Result**
[image]
Any Idea how to solve my problem or any mistake I did ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your database like this

```
$this->db_report = $this->CI->load->database('reportcallcenter', TRUE);
```

assumed that 'qm' db will be set as default

or you can try like this

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('qm', TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('reportcallcenter', TRUE);
```

then you can use like

```
$DB1->query();
$DB1->result();
```

and

```
$DB2->query();
$DB2->result();
```

in your case try like

```
if($query = $DB2->get_all())
{
    $data['recordings_record'] = $query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gautam3164 reply, after I added your load ,but it's still return me same error shown server error

Comment: Have you set $active_record = TRUE; for both the connections..??

Comment: ya, both also as TRUE, I uploaded new error, better than my previous error now, any idea how to solve the error ? i think it's almost there :)

Comment: Try to add this $DB1 = $this->load->database('qm', TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('reportcallcenter', TRUE); in your controller function

Comment: I had try put in _construct and in my function, if put in _construct, it's will show me the 2nd screen shot error, if put in my function, it's will show me 1st screen shot error

Comment: may be check that your 'reportcallcenter' has configured corectly and loading or not

Comment: thanks Gautam3164, it's working now, because my colleague gave me wrong password lol

Comment: Oh glad it helps for you,bec after you said that its not working,iam cha=ecking at my local....good...you can upvote it even

Comment: Thaks you too,bec I had checked mine once again after a longtime